# PhpStorm - Configuring deployment remote server for debug

Tags: phpstorm, zend-framework3, phpstorm-2018.1

I want to debug in a remote server, which is, by the way, a Vagrant machine. Not really a remote server, but this has a peculiar setup: the shared host/vagrant machine folder isn't related to the web server files.

The server is configured with Zend Framework.
I have, locally, to deploy to the machine the following folders (as Zend Framework structure):

```
/home/user/webStuff/web
```

- Inside web: config, data, module, vendor and public folders
- Inside public folder I have the index.php, which handles all server requests.

Following is the server deployment configuration:
 [image: Deployment configuration 1]

When I press "Test SFTP Connection" everything is fine. When I press "Open", the website opens.

And here, is the "Mappings" tab on the deployment configuration

[image: Deployment configuration 2]

Everything seems OK, here. At least from my point of view.
But when I test the settings, in `Run -> WebServer Debug Validation`, it gives me "Failed to collect files: Invalid relative file name". I've tried more settings, like placing `/web/public` in Web path, but with no success.

In `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP` I have a good configuration for the server vagrantmachine.com, with XDebug version correctly displayed.

Also, I've placed the following in xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

I've searched and tried a lot, but with no success.
I'm no specialist in these server configuration things, but if you need any information, just ask.

Comment: What is the point behind setting the root path to `/home/vagrant` and then going up in the mappings?
Try setting `/opt/webStuff` directly and then set the mappings to be just `/`.

Comment: /home/vagrant/ was autodetected. I believe I already tried that setting but I will confirm later. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deployment path on server" and "Root Path" were wrong.
Like @Eugene Morozov said, I changed the root path to "/opt/webStuff" and deployment path to "/" and it worked out.